# How to verify POST documentation in Apiary

Tags: apiary.io, apiary

I've created a couple of C# unit tests that perform GETs on the Apiary mock server and check that the JSON returned (i.e. the documentation) matches the statically-typed object I expect to be returned (hence checking that the documentation matches the actual implementation).

I can't see how to do something similar for POST data though. Does the Apiary mock server provide any information about whether a POST request that it has received matches the expected request in the blueprint?

I'm currently using the legacy syntax for blueprint documentation, I don't know if that makes any difference?

Answer (score 0):

Apiary definitely provides support to your use case.

You should have a look to the built in inspector. You can find it usually under this link: http://docs.yourSubdomain.apiary.io/traffic

Let me know if I can help further.